# How to implement multi level expandable list view search functionality?

Tags: android, search, expandablelistview

I want to implement search functionality in multi level Expandable list view. The hierarchy should expand during Search has progressed.

Can anyone plz help me to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please help me.. I am in critical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            if (!list.get(i).isExpanded()
                    && list.get(i).getWrappedObject().getLevel() != 0) {
                list.get(i).toggle();
            }
        }
```